# Enum support in MvvmCross data-binding

Tags: mvvmcross

I have an enum property in the view-model and I want to make a label visible if the property value is of a specific value

```
States state;
public States State
{
    get { return this.state; }
    set
    {
        if (this.state != value)
        {
            this.state = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("State");
        }
    }
}

public enum States
{
    Stopped,
    Runnning
}
```

here's what I tried in the UI:

```
local:MvxBind="Visibility If(State==1, 'Visible', 'Gone')"
```

but it doesn't work. No error is displayed in the log.

I can make a converter but I was wondering if it's possible to do it without it.

If I modify the State property to use int instead of Enum, it works fine. 
I guess it has to do with how currently Enum type is handled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Tibet binding addons, statements like:

```
 If(State==1, 'Visible', 'Gone'
```

are not compiled because of iOS JIT limitations - instead they are evaluated.

Sadly the evaluation of operators like `==` turned out to be quite difficult to do without using dynamic code...

Because of this, what the Tibet `==` operator tries to do is to reduce the right and left sides down to one of three types: `long`, `double` or `object` - it does this using:

```
    private Type GetLookupTypeFor(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        if (value is long)
            return typeof(long);
        if (value is double)
            return typeof (double);
        return typeof (object);
    }
```

from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding/Combiners/MvxPairwiseValueCombiner.cs#L36

with these types determined it then calls one of these methods, each of which uses the `==` operator of the left-hand type or `.Equals` if both types are `object`:

```
    protected override bool CombineDoubleAndDouble(double input1, double input2, out object value)
    {
        value = input1 == input2;
        return true;
    }
    protected override bool CombineDoubleAndLong(double input1, long input2, out object value)
    {
        value = input1 == input2;
        return true;
    }
    // ... etc
```

from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding/Combiners/VeryExperimental/MvxEqualToValueCombiner.cs

For the `enum` case of `State==1`, I think the left-hand will be identified as an `object` and the right-hand as a `long` - so these will never be equal because of:

```
    protected override bool CombineObjectAndLong(object input1, long input2, out object value)
    {
        value = false;
        return true;
    }
```

Working with the current code, I think the only way to get the test to work is to get both left and right-side to `long` or to `string`.

You could do that using a value converter on the enum - e.g. a `ToStringValueConverter` or a `ToLongValueConverter` which you could then use like:

```
 If(ToLong(State)==1, 'Visible', 'Gone'
```

or:

```
 If(ToString(State)=='Running', 'Visible', 'Gone'
```

Obviously, looking forwards, this area could also be improved inside Mvx - in whatever lies beyond `Swiss` and `Tibet`

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation Stuart. What are the reasons why having a built-in ToString() converter (or even combiner with one step) doesn't make sense? It would make data-binding work for almost any type.

Comment: There's no built-in ToString converter because it's **never** been requested. Hope that makes sense. Over and out for here - stackoverflow discourages followup q's and conversations in comments.